# Modal suddenly disapearring

Tags: plugins, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap Modals plugin.
I have put the following code for modal in my page-contact.php.

```
<h2>Small Modal</h2>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Small Modal</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
<div class="modal-content">

<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
<p>This is a small modal.</p>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div> `
```

After clicking the button open modal, modal is appearing, and suddenly disappears. Weird is also that in the right top angle I have an x for closing the modal.
Can someone advice?

Regards, Ivana

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good.

You may have some more JavaScript code that is making some confict. Try changing the parameters id

In the button
`data-target="#myModal"`
to
`data-target="#myModal-custom"`

And the modal window `id="myModal"` to `id="myModal-custom"`

Please read the official documentation of [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

Answer (score 0):

If your theme already uses Bootstrap then there could be conflict. Loading twice the bootstrap.js  would cause what you described. If you are going to remove one of the two bootstrap js make sure the css is also of the same version. eg. Bootstrap 3.6 js and Boostrap 3.6 css

I had an issue like this when one of my team uploaded the js of Bootstrap 3.4 but not the css and resulted on weird behaviors.